# Can`t change Foreground in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I created *DataGrid* and put background to bi transparent. Now i want to set foreground to be Blue but it does`t want to change, always is black. I try to put *Foreground="Blue"* in all those places but never worked.

```
<DataGrid Background="Transparent" Foreground="Blue">
        <DataGrid.Columns Foreground="Blue">
            <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Blue" Header="AAA"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Blue" Header="BBB"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Blue" Header="CCC"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Blue" Header="DDD"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I have this in my *App.xaml* so maybe there is some Themes that affect it but i don`t know how to overwrite it.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Indigo.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Do you want to set different foreground color to every row or a single color to entire datagrid text?

Comment: Just same color for entire datagrid

Comment: Try to keep the Foreground on DataGrid level and then check.

Comment: I did try separately on DataGrid then on DataGrid.Columns and on the DataGridTextColumn  but it didn`t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fore some reason that don`t work in my project, there is some theme applied and overwrite wherever i put Foreground. What i did is put in DataGridTextColumn.Header Label and sat Foreground of Label and that worked. And i did it for every DataGridTextColumn in my DataGrid

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <Label Foreground="#FF0398E2" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16">Name</Label>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's a template being applied to each of the cells and wpf doesn't always inherit down into template generated ui.

You could try putting this in your datagrid:

```
 <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
           <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
      </Style>
 </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Fore some reason that don`t work in my project, there is some theme applied and overwrite it.What i did is put in DataGridTextColumn.Header Label and sat Foreground of Label and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some data to the datagrid to see what your code is doing:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MockList"   XPath="/MockObjects/*" >
      <x:XData >
        <MockObjects xmlns="">
          <MockObject  Name="Louis" Type="TTTT" Number="1" />
          <MockObject Name="Joseph" Type="TTTT" Number="2" />
          <MockObject Name="Papineau" Type="ZZZZ" Number="3" />
        </MockObjects>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MockList}}">
    <DataGrid Background="Transparent" Name="MainDataGrid" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=Default, XPath=/MockObjects/MockObject}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Blue" Header="AAA" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Blue" Header="BBB" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Type}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Blue" Header="CCC" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Number}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Blue" Header="DDD"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

It seems that DataGridTextColumn Foreground sets the foreground of the data, not the header.

The header seems to inherit its  Foreground from DataGrid.Foreground. Make the following change in my code:

```
<DataGrid Background="Transparent" Name="MainDataGrid" Foreground="Blue"
```

[image]

To investigate how the value inheritance works (or if the value does come from a template), set a breakpoint in your program:

[image]

Run the program and double click on the datagrid. Quickwatch MainDataGrid and open the WPF Tree Visualiser

[image]

[image]

The TextBlock is displaying the column header text. It inherits Foreground blue from all the lines marked yellow. Only the MainDataGrid does not inherit the value, but is set locally in XAML. The Treeview gives you this information if you click on MainDataGrid Foreground.

Note: This line in your code does not compile

```
<DataGrid.Columns Foreground="Blue">
```

DataGrid.Columns doesn't have a Foreground property.

It's well know that getting the formatting of the WPF DataGrid to work properly is a major headache. I recommend you read my article on codeproject [Guide to WPF DataGrid Formatting Using Bindings](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-Formatting-Using-Bindings) to see samples for all kind of datagrid formatting.

Comment: Fore some reason that don`t work in my project, there is some theme applied and overwrite it.What i did is put in DataGridTextColumn.Header Label and sat Foreground of Label and that worked.

Comment: Good that you found a solution working for you. It would be interesting to see where the Foreground black value came from in your old solution. Did you try to investigate it with the WPF Visual tree Analizer and looking at the source of the TextBlock.Foreground property ?